# Updating a ListView on MainActivity from Asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, listadapter

I have a list view on the main Ui that I wish to update through an Asynctask which connects to a Mikrotik device to retrieve details.

I am passing the activity too, so that I can update the UI from a separate class file, however I keep getting the error "Class name expected here" for the activity (mActivity) in the ListAdapter constructor.

Here is the Asynctask code:

```
public class MikrotikReader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    //Default connection details for mikrotik
    private int mkPort = 8728;
    private int mkTimeout = 5000;
    private String userName;
    private String userPass;
    private String mkIpAddress;
    private String mkCommand;
    private ListView listView;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public MikrotikReader(String user, String pass, String ipaddress, String command, Activity activity) {
        this.userName = user;
        this.userPass = pass;
        this.mkIpAddress = ipaddress;
        this.mkCommand = command;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }



    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {


        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            ApiConnection con = ApiConnection.connect(SocketFactory.getDefault(), mkIpAddress, mkPort, mkTimeout);
            con.login(userName, userPass); // log in to router
            if (con.isConnected()) {
                List<Map<String, String>> rs1 = con.execute(mkCommand);
                for (Map<String, String> results1 : rs1) {
                    getResults[0] = new String(results1.get("comment"));
                    mylist.add(getResults[0]);
                }
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (MikrotikApiException e) {
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mylist;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> mylist) {

        System.out.println("This is the array content " + mylist.get(0));

        listView = (ListView) mActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new ArrayList<String>())); }
```

This is how I call the Asynctask from the MainActivity class file, passing "this" as the activity:

```
new MikrotikReader(user_name, password, ipaddress,"/ip/firewall/filter/print where comment=Test", this).execute();
```

Here is the listview in the mainactivity.xml file:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
```

Comment: This is not correct way to update the list view in another activity.Dont put this asyn task in the different class.You can either use interface or simpley put this in same class.Then you don't need to pass Activity.

Comment: I was told that best practice is to have separate reusable class files, to maintain object oriented code, and pass data between them.  

Since I have other class files that process async tasks to retrieve or write data to the Mikrotik device, do you suggest I implement them all i the same class file?
  

That would result in a chunky main_activity file. Is that the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

try to use only mActivity instead mActivity.this in yout AsyncTask class

Answer (score 0):

Don't do like this. 
Make interface like

```
    public interface ListPreparingListener {
void onListPrepared(ArrayList<String> mylist);
}
```

And implement it on your main activity like

```
@Override
onListPrepared(ArrayList<String> myList) {
 listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new ArrayList<String>()));
}
```

Then, pass this interface to you reader's constructor and call this method on post execute

Upd:
Actually it could produce memory leak, if you store a reference to your activity inside other objects. The most proper way is to make methods `subscribeListener` and `unsubsucribeListener` and subscribe when you need it from main activity, unsubscribe `onStop`. Also on your onPostExecute should be check if there are available listeners